# Showing a particular error in every post , I am creating

Tags: php, wordpress

Notice: Undefined variable: posted_on in /home/iz9d3yugs2u3/public_html/wp-content/themes/total/inc/template-tags.php on line 44

This error is continuously coming on my each and every post , Can you help me out , how to remove this error ??

I was trying to remove this error by following the given path in cpanel but when I reached the destination file everything was fine .

Comment: Apparently you're trying to access `$posted_on` in `template-tags.php` on line 44, but the variable doesn't exist. You don't show any code, so we cannot tell you why.

Comment: okay ,  but this the error , I am getting . How Can I paste the  whole file in comment section

Comment: Never post code in comments, it never formats well. Instead, you can [edit] your post and add the code there.